# Filter AnyObject in Swift 2

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift2, anyobject

I have an JsonArray named data which I pass to AnyObject:

```
 if let dtMenu: AnyObject = responseObject?.valueForKey("data") {
                   print(filteredMenu)
                 }
```

// I got JsonArray here
// My data are

```
 "data":[
    {
    "MENUITEMID":1.0,
    "MENUITEMNAMEENG":"IGW",
    "MENUITEMHREF":"IGW_1",
    "MENUITEMTYPE":"R",
    "MENUITEMLEVEL":1.0,
    "MENUGRPID":0.0,
    "MENUGRPSERIAL":1.0
    },
    {
    "MENUITEMID":6.0,
    "MENUITEMNAMEENG":"Dashboard",
    "MENUITEMHREF":"Dashboard_IGW",
    "MENUITEMTYPE":"L",
    "MENUITEMLEVEL":2.0,
    "MENUGRPID":1.0,
    "MENUGRPSERIAL":1.0
    }]
```

//I want to filter array by MENUITEMTYPE=R

Please help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
    var predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K == %@", "MENUITEMTYPE", "R")

    let filteredArray = yourArray.filter { predicate.evaluateWithObject($0) };
```

I have not tested this yet.